# DataGrid gets the value of a row and column

Tags: datagrid, syncfusion, winui-3

I want to get the value of a certain cell in the DataGrid of syncfusion.

like this:

```
<dataGrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="sfDataGrid">         
</dataGrid:SfDataGrid>
```

C#:

```
           Sfdatagrid\[i,j\] is useless.
```

How do I get the value of this cell.

https://help.syncfusion.com/winui/datagrid/overview The document
In this official document, I didn't find out how to get the value of this cell according to the index of rows and columns.

I want to get the value of this cell according to the index of the row and column.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

For example, I want to get the value of this cell according to the index of the row and column.

How should I write code in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement to get the value of this cell according to the index of the row and column in SfDataGrid can be achieved by using **View.GetPropertyAccessProvider.GetValue** method in SfDatGrid. Please refer the below code snippet,

```
   private void OnGetCellValueClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        // Get the cell value for RowIndex = 5 and ColumnIndex = 2            
        int rowIndex = 5;
        int columnIndex = dataGrid.ResolveToGridVisibleColumnIndex(2);

        object record = null;

        if (columnIndex < 0)
            return;

        var provider = this.dataGrid.View.GetPropertyAccessProvider();           

        var mappingName = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex].MappingName;

        var recordIndex = this.dataGrid.ResolveToRecordIndex(rowIndex);

        if (this.dataGrid.View.TopLevelGroup != null)
        {
            var displayElement = this.dataGrid.View.TopLevelGroup.DisplayElements[recordIndex];

            if (displayElement == null)
                return;
            if (displayElement is RecordEntry)
                record = ((RecordEntry)displayElement).Data;
        }
        else
        {
            record = this.dataGrid.View.Records[recordIndex].Data;
            if (record == null)
                return;
        }            
        var cellValue = provider.GetValue(record, mappingName);

        //here display the cell value for RowIndex = 5 and ColumnIndex = 2
        if (cellValue != null)
            txtGetCellValue.Text = cellValue.ToString();
   }
```